# USE PHP to echo portion of text to another page or Div

Tags: php, echo

I'm new to PHP and any help or direction would be great! I don't need the answer necessarily, just some input. I would like to display a portion of text fro one page onto a div of another page.

PAGE 1

```
<div id="content">
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab     illo 
</div>
```

PAGE 2

```
<div id="portionofcontent">
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the text you want to pull into various pages into its own file called whatever.php and then use `<?php include('whatever.php'); ?>` inside the div.

update:
You could make a file called `yourtext.php` with this code:

`<?php $text = 'Put the text you want to display on multiple pages here.'; ?>`

Then put `<?php include('yourtext.php'); ?>` in the header of your file somewhere and use `<?php echo $text; ?>` in the content of your page where you want to display the text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, that's not necessarily what I'm trying to achieve. I want just a portion of the text on page 1, not the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's static text then it's pretty much what ennui said but I would go another way:

There are also many ways to read in a file.  If it's just plain text, you might be better with `file_get_contents($file)` assuming it's not a large file.

Try this:

content.txt

`This is part of a rather long sentence which goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on until finally it reaches the end`

page1.php

```
<?php  
 $txt = file_get_contents('./content.txt');
 echo $txt;
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php    
 $txt = file_get_contents('./content.txt');
 echo substr($txt, 0, 100); //substring(text, start, length) nb. start is from 0
?>
```

You can also use commands like `fopen`, `fgets` to open the file and read only a part of the file but I think it might be a bit complicated for you at this stage